# Doing paralel jobs with python

Tags: python

Hi all I need help with my Python 3 program

I have a project with a card reader which is attached to a Raspberry pi 3 that has single core CPU (Number of core matters when it comes to threding If I am not mistaken)
What I have done so far is running an infinite loop and inside that loop waiting for new cards and when new cards appear, write their number to a text file in JSON format. So far it works well. Right here I need a parallel job inside my program that look for updates in that file and uploaded them to the server without blocking main card reader loop. What I mean looks something like this:

```
def sync_to_the_cloud():
    read_file()
    sync()

def main():
    while True:
        newCard = wait_for_card():
            if newCard is not None:
                write_to_file():
```

Which python library should I use for this? I read a lot and I am confused now. threading, multiprocessing or asyncio? I also confused with the terms. What I want is called concurrent program or asynchronous program?